# Does GKE Autopilot sometimes kill Pods and is there a way to prevent it for Critical Services?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, redis, celery, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been debugging a 10min downtime of our service for some hours now, and I seem to have found the cause, but not the reason for it. Our redis deployment in kubernetes was down for quite a while, causing neither django nor redis to be able to reach it. This caused a bunch of jobs to be lost.

There are no events for the redis deployment, but here are the first logs before and after the reboot:

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

I'm also attaching the complete redis yml at the bottom. We're using GKE Autopilot, so I guess something caused the pod to reboot? Resource usage is a lot lower than requested, at about 1% for both CPU and memory. Not sure what's going on here. I also couldn't find an annotation to tell Autopilot to leave a specific deployment alone

redis.yml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gce-ssd
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "2Gi"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      name: redis
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: redis
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: redis-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: redis-disk
            readOnly: false
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:6-alpine
          command: ["sh"]
          args: ["-c", 'exec redis-server --requirepass "$REDIS_PASSWORD"']
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
              ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: env-secrets
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-volume
              mountPath: /data
              subPath: data
```

Comment: I would recommend to not run a service with a single replica. Pods in Kubernetes and VM in cloud is intended to be disposable - you must eliminated single point of failure by using a **clustered Redis** in production environments.

Comment: @Jonas, you are correct, but 10 min of unavailability isn't normal, the pod should be restarted immediately by the control plane. I would recommend to ask the support instead

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere if a node becomes unreachable then 10 minutes is normal, node health check is not run so often.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jonas and a clustered redis seems like a great choice. However for postgres we'd still be stuck on a single point of failure and using google's own SQL services would be more expensive by an order of magnitude

Comment: I would recommend to always use distributed solutions for production environments, e.g. https://www.cockroachlabs.com/product/kubernetes/ is a PostgreSQL compatible database that can run on Kubernetes.

Comment: Any chance your cluster version was updated?  Do you have the actual pod logs/event?

Comment: what do you mean by actual pod logs events? The events were empty and the logs are screenshotted above. I think the events are pruned at some point so I might've just been too late, not sure.

Comment: Usually `kubectl desc pod redis-xxxx-xxxx`  should show the last few events / log for the pod

Answer (score 2):

`PersistentVolumeClaim` is an object in *kubernetes* allowing to decouple storage resource requests from actual resource provisioning done by its associated `PersistentVolume` part.

Given:

- no declared `PersistentVolume` object
- [and Dynamic Provisioning being enabled on your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#using-dynamic-provisioning)

*kubernetes* will try to **dynamically provision** a suitable persistent disk for you suitable for the underlying infrastructure being a [*Google Compute Engine Persistent Disk*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk) in you case based on the requested *storage class* (*gce-ssd*).

The claim will result then in an SSD-like Persistent Disk to be automatically provisioned for you and **once the claim is deleted** (the requesting pod is deleted due to downscale), **the volume is destroyed**.

To overcome this issue and avoid precious data loss, you should have two alternatives:

### At the PersistentVolumeClaim level

To avoid data loss once the Pod and its PVC are deleted, you can set the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` parameter to `Retain` on the PVC object:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gce-ssd
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "2Gi"
```

This allows for the persistent volume to go back to the `Released` state and the underlying data can be **manually** backed up.

### At the StorageClass level

As a general recommendation, you should set the `reclaimPolicy` parameter to `Retain` (default is `Delete`) for your used `StorageClass`:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
  reclaimPolicy: Retain
  replication-type: regional-pd
  volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Additional parameters are recommended:

- `replication-type`: should be set to `regional-pd` to allow zonal replication
- `volumeBindingMode`: set to `WaitForFirstConsumer` to allow for first consumer dictating the zonal replication topology

You can read more on all above [`StorageClass` parameters in the *kubernetes* documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

A `PersistentVolume` with same storage class name is then declared:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: ssd-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: "ssd"
  capacity:
    storage: 2G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: redis-disk
```

And the `PersistentVolumeClaim` would only declare the requested `StorageClass` name:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ssd-volume-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: "ssd"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "2Gi"

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: redis-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ssd-volume-claim
            readOnly: false
```

This objects declaration would prevent any failures or scale down operations from destroying the created PV either created manually by cluster administrators or dynamically using *Dynamic Provisioning*.